# Custom spinner adapter not working

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my custom spinner and Spinner Adapter. It crashes after I launch it.I wanted to change the color and background color of the text at my spinner so I created a XML file my_spinner.xml which looks this way:

```
 <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/spinner_item_linear_layout" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView        
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="@color/White"
  android:background="@color/Blue"
  android:id="@+id/spinner_textView" >        
</TextView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Then I made a MyAdapter class which looks like this:
    public class ProjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {

```
    public ProjectAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater =  getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_spinner, parent, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner_textView);
        tv.setText(projectList.get(position));

        return row;

    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {    
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

}
```

and i use the ProjectAdapter there:

```
  spinnerProject.setAdapter(new ProjectAdapter(this, R.layout.my_spinner, projectList));
```

can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help

Comment: What's wrong with it then? hard to help when we dont know.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. The program crashes after I launch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this

```
 View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_spinner, parent, false);
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner_textView);
```

to

```
 View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_spinner, parent, false);
 TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_textView);
```

One of the mistakes. Without stacktrace its difficult to track the mistakes. If you have further problems suggest you post the stacktrace