# Setting selection on Spinner crashes layout

Tags: android, spinner

I have a quite a simple layout with a `Spinner` in it, that has my own adapter attached to it.

```
MyAdapter myAdap = new MyAdapter();
mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdap);
```

The adapter has two items (from debugger):

```
myAdap.getCount() = 2
```

When I set the selection to `1` though (`0` works),

```
mySpinner.setSelection(1);
```

the app crashes:

```
10-05 19:37:17.122 19899-19899/nl.example.demo E/test: Exception 10-05 19:37:17.142 19899-19899/nl.example.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-05 19:37:17.142 19899-19899/nl.example.demo E/AndroidRuntime: Process: example.demo, PID: 19899 10-05 19:37:17.142 19899-19899/nl.example.demo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-05 19:37:17.142 19899-19899/nl.example.demo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6151) 
10-05 19:37:17.142 19899-19899/nl.example.demo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6427) 
10-05 19:37:17.142 19899-19899/nl.example.demo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
[..]
```

The strange thing, is that this works on another phone with the same version of Android, but a smaller screen.

`MyAdapter` is as follows:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    static ArrayList<String> methods = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, 0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        if (methods == null) {
            methods = new ArrayList<String>();
            methods.add("1");
            methods.add("2");
            methods.add("3");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return methods.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return methods.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        }
        TextView tvLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tvLabel.setText("test");
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Update** my Nexus 6 does not have the problem.

Comment: Error is in your `TextView`, please share your MyAdapter class

Comment: @RahulParihar updated my question

Comment: Are you sure this is Java?

Comment: @Onik, yes. What makes you doubt that?

Comment: @Bart Friederichs Couple of things: 1) How come the constructor `PickMethodAdapter` doesn't match the class name? 2) I can see the return type of the `getItem` method is `PickMethod` whilst the actual return type is `String`?...Well, either I'm suck at Java after 2,5 years of coding or it's a copy-paste error on your side...

Comment: @Onik, it was late when I posted the code. I tried to make it simpler (there is more code in my adapter than this) and failed. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should modify the code like this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
TextView tvLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        }else{ 
        tvLabel.setText("test");
        return convertView;}
    }
```

as `findViewById` should only be called when convertview is null.
also you were missing the return convertview tag

Comment: How do you explain that it does work on another phone with smaller screen size?

Comment: notice that I edited my answer, 
as for screen size it affects the calling of get view, I had almost same issue, then realized that the view recycling is the reason for the certain textview to become null or be recycled.

Comment: you could also forget about recycling views like this example of custom spinner adapter here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593026/custom-spinner-adapter-not-working

Comment: I'll check it out. For my understanding, wouldn't that cause the `NullPointerException` to be thrown in the `getView` method, instead of somewhere in `ChoreoGrapher` ?